# Entity Framework code first relationship using fluent API to string

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have the following classses

```
public pratial class Address
{
    public Guid AddressID{ get; set; }
    public AddressType AddressType{ get; set; }
}

public partial class AddressType
{
    public string TypeName{ get; set; }
}
```

In my derived DBContext class I have overridden OnModelCreating

```
protected override OnModelCreating(DBModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasKey( p => p.AddressID );
    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().Property ( p => p.AddressID)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasRequired( p => p.AddressType);
    modelBuilder.Entity<AddrssType>().HasKey( p => p.TypeName );

    ...
}
```

This creates fine I fill out a record in the database where

My Tables in the database end up looking like this

```
Addresses Table
AddressID (PK, uniqueidentified, not null)
AddressType_TypeName(FK, nvarchar(32), not null)

AddressTypes Table
TypeName (PK, uniqueidentifies, not null)
```

Now I put some data in the tables

AddressTypes Record
TypeName I put in Business

in the Addresses Record 
AddressType_TypeName I put in Business

When I run a unit test on this I expect to get back in for my record

```
List<Address> addresses = context.Addresses.ToList()
Assert.AreEqual(addresses[0].AddressType.TypeName, "Business");
```

But this fails telling me AddressType is null

How do I set up the relationship between Address and AddressType so that I get back the AddressType that I've hooked up?

Answer (score 0):

To load related entities you must tell it Entity Framework, either by using *eager loading*:

```cs
using System.Data.Entity;

//...

var addresses = context.Addresses.Include(a => a.AddressType).ToList()
```

...or by *lazy loading* which is enabled by default if you mark your navigation properties as `virtual`:

```cs
public virtual AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
```

Eager loading loads the parent and related data together in a single database roundtrip. Lazy loading needs two roundtrips, the second happens under the convers when you access the navigation property in the line `addresses[0].AddressType.TypeName`.

**Edit**

Test project to show that lazy loading in this example works (EF 5.0, .NET 4.0, SQL Server Express 2008 R2 as database). I only put `virtual` in front of `AddressType`. The rest is identical to your model:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace EFLazyLoading
{
    public partial class Address
    {
        public Guid AddressID{ get; set; }
        public virtual AddressType AddressType{ get; set; }
    }

    public partial class AddressType
    {
        public string TypeName{ get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AddressType> AddressTypes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasKey( p => p.AddressID );
            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().Property ( p => p.AddressID)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasRequired( p => p.AddressType);
            modelBuilder.Entity<AddressType>().HasKey( p => p.TypeName );
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());
            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                var address = new Address
                {
                    AddressType = new AddressType { TypeName = "Business" }
                };
                ctx.Addresses.Add(address);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                List<Address> addresses = ctx.Addresses.ToList();

                string typeName = addresses[0].AddressType.TypeName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result of `typeName` in the last line is as expected:

[image: Lazy loading]

Comment: Neither of those work for me. Include in not part of IQueryable is the error from the first and I still get null for the AddessType from the second. I'm thinking it's something to do with how I'm creating the keys in OnModelCreating.

Comment: @MarkToth: `OnModelCreating` is fine as far as I can see. Did you put `using System.Data.Entity;` at the beginning of your code file? It is required to have `Include` available. For the second: Do you have `ProxyCreationEnabled = false` or `LazyLoadingEnabled = false` set for your context?

Comment: I want to use lazy loading anyway so the first solution is not really what I want since it wont always be necessary for me to know the type of address.  I don't want to have to use include in my repository pattern unless it's absolutely necessary.  I'm thinking it's because the Key in AddressTypes isn't named conventionally ie AddressTypeID but I also don't want an ID key in AddressType since it's redundant in that the TypeName field will be unique.  Does that make sense?  My aplogies I should have been more specific about the Repository Pattern I'm using.

Comment: @MarkToth: The key name is not conventional, but you override the convention correctly with `HasKey(p => p.TypeName)`. I don't see a problem here. Why doesn't lazy loading work? Did you check the `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` and `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` settings? They must be both `true`.

Comment: Yes both are true.  I even now went to the extent of settng them to true in the constructor for my Repository and still the same thing.  I do have other classes that are loading fine. I have a customer with and ICollection<Address> and that lazy loads fine.  But even in that collection the AddressType is null.

Comment: @MarkToth: Can you check in the debugger if the loaded addresses in the `addresses` collection are dynamic proxies? You can see it by looking at the type, the type name should be `Dynamic_proxyBlahBlah...` instead of `Address`.

Comment: Yes System.Data.Entity.DymanicProxies.Address_blahblahblah
but the AddressType in the Address is
BarrettJackson.Core.Domain.Concrete.AddressType

Comment: @MarkToth: That's OK. `AddressType` is not expected to be a dynamic proxy. But I've just seen that you say in your question that the PK `TypeName` in your `AddressType` table is a `uniqueidentifier` (=Guid). That would not be correct. It must be a `nvarchar` like the FK in `Address`.

Comment: no typo sorry about that it's TypeName (PK, nvarchar(32), not null) and in the Addresses Table the key is AddressType_TypeName (FK, nvarchar(32), not null)

Comment: @MarkToth: Wow, that's a really hidden problem. The last idea I have is: Do the key values in PK and FK in the DB are identical with respect to small and capital letters? It might be a problem for EF to link `Address` with `AddressType` if you have `"Business"` and `"business"` for example. The SQL query will work (not case sensitive) but relationship fixup in the EF context possibly not.

Comment: Yes I copied and pasted the key "Business" from AddressType to Address.  I know right it's driving me crazy.  I think a work around might be not to depend on the relationship at all.  Use the AddressType table to only fill up selection lists and then just store it as a string in the Addresses table.  That would probably work but I'm a bit obsessive compulsive about solving a problem like this.  I've tried various things over the past 2 days and finally reached out here :(

Comment: I going to research using Enums to do this.  Maybe that's what I truely want anyway.  I found a video on that at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx

Comment: @MarkToth: I've made a small test project, see my Edit above. It works. Somewhere must be an important difference we don't see and that must explain why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hum wierd.  Perhaps it's because I didn't use code to set the TypeName but did it directly in the database.  Perhaps that was the problem because when I now initialize the Address and add in my unittest.  It's fine.  Strange that I can't do it directly in the database.  Oh and thanks for the tip on the Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());
I've been changing the database name each time to get it to create a new database.  That makes my life easier.  Anyway now it's working.  A million thanks  Slauma!

Comment: OK now here's wierd.  Now I run my test again without recreating the database and adding the Address (just read what's currently in the Database) and it's null again.

Comment: When I examine the type that was retrived from when I create the Address in code it's BarrettJackson.Core.Concrete.Address and NOT System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Address_blahblahblah.  That is why the AddressType is there.  So I'm back to square one.

Comment: @MarkToth: If you want to create a proxy manually to enable lazy loading use `Address address = context.Addresses.Create();`, not `new Address()`.

Comment: when I create it that way OR read directly from the database the AddressType is null!